The differences between two solutions to the Dutch flag problem
I have some doubts about the solution to this problem:
https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-colors/description/

Why must 2 be processed first and then 0 when traversing from left to right? And why must 0 be processed first and then 2 when traversing from right to left?

Why must the if statement when num[i]==0 be changed to a while statement when traversing from right to left?


I want to know the deep-seated reasons for these phenomena. Thank you.
Solution of traversing from left to right:
class Solution {
    public void swap(int[] nums, int i, int j) {
        int temp = nums[i];
        nums[i] = nums[j];
        nums[j] = temp;
    }
    public void sortColors(int[] nums) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = nums.length - 1;
        // Traverse from left to right.
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            // first "2", then "0", the order is irreversible.
            while (i < end && nums[i] == 2) {
                swap(nums, end, i);
                end--;
            }
            if (nums[i] == 0) { // or `while (i > start && nums[i] == 0)`
                swap(nums, start, i);
                start++;
            }
        }
    }
}

Solution of traversing from right to left:
class Solution {
    public void swap(int[] nums, int i, int j) {
        int temp = nums[i];
        nums[i] = nums[j];
        nums[j] = temp;
    }
    public void sortColors(int[] nums) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = nums.length - 1;
        // Traverse from right to left.
        for (int i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // first "0", then "2", the order is irreversible.
            while (i > start && nums[i] == 0) { // Cannot use `if (nums[i] == 0)`.
                swap(nums, start, i);
                start++;
            }
            while (i < end && nums[i] == 2) {
                swap(nums, end, i);
                end--;
            }
        }
    }
}


It is not a matter what is processed first, since that is determined by i. It is a matter of where you want to move a value to, and obviously you want to move a 2 to the (right) end and a 0 to the (left) start. And as the comment in the first code snippet said, you can use a while there too. And where you put a comment in the second snippet: that is not the loop where you could use an if. It is at the second inner loop.

You could also make the code agnostic to the actual values of 0, 1 and 2. Just swap if num[x] > num[x+1]. See Bubble sort

When traversing from left to right, after swapping 2 to the end, there may be a 0 swapped over. At this time, this 0 needs to be processed continuously. For example, for [2,1,0,0,2], after swapping, it becomes [0,1,0,2,2]. Then at this time, this 0 must be processed, that is, swap(nums, 0, 0). If 0 is processed first and then 2, when processing 2 and a 0 is swapped over, the swap(nums, 0, 0) operation will not be executed.
Why must swap(nums, 0, 0) be executed? Because after execution, it is start++, and then start will point to the next position of the consecutive segment of 0s. In this way, when encountering 0 in the future, a swap can be done directly once without using while. (Using while is because after swapping, the current element may not change. Therefore, swap needs to be executed in a loop. But at this time, we must be swapping a non-zero element and 0, so it can be executed only once.)
From right to left, similarly. Therefore, in the solution from right to left, change
            while (i < end && nums[i] == 2) {

to
            if (nums[i] == 2) {

is also feasible and more standard.
